# Change the border of a layer in GeoServer

Tags: geoserver

I have a layer of all roads of my country in GeoServer, the problem is that some of the roads are outside of the borders of the country, but I need to include only those that are inside. Changing bounding boxes does not help since as I understood it can only be a rectangle shaped border, but I need it to be the shape of my country.

Here is what I have on layer preview:

[image]

So as you can see, there are some roads that are outside of a country. What is the way to make a filter or something to change the layer?

Comment: Best way is to clip sources data.

Answer (score 1):

At the bottom of your layer page there is a box that you can add a CQL filter to limit the data in your layer:

[image]